# Should [bigquery] be remapped to [google-bigquery]?

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The bigquery tag has 55 questions, while google-bigquery has 11,500 questions. The bigquery tag's [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bigquery/info) makes it clear it's only about Google's product.

This proposal has 2 votes already, but I don't have the tag reputation needed to vote:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-bigquery/synonyms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: yes! Completed by Cody Gray, I presume. Thanks for voting, everyone.

Comment: Yup. I merged the tags and created a synonym. We generally just track this by adding a moderator-only status tag to the question. But that does have the downside of leaving the question “unanswered” in the system’s logic.